# Joomla 3.0 - Checkbox Error (2nd Checkmark Appears)

Tags: css, checkbox, joomla3.0, chronoforms

I created a form using Chronoforms for Joomla 3.0. All works well, except a second blue checkmark appears when you check a box in the Checkboxes Group.

I can't find the CSS styling to disable this occurrence.

Site:
        http://www.greenwoodac.com/get-a-quote

Thanks for your assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Beez3 template has form styling included. The CSS is at http://www.greenwoodac.com/templates/beez3/css/layout.css line 362:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #FEFEFE, #0B70CD) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #0B70CD;
    content: "✔";
    text-indent: 0;
```